# MVC 5 - foreach loop within Model (generating html)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Razor code which is static and needs to be constructed from the Model:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 hidden-sm">
            <h4>@Resource.Title</h4>
            <p>@Resource.Header_Date</p>
            <img src="~/Content/Images/student.png" alt="student" />
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9">
            <h4>@Resource.Header_ListTitle</h4>
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <ul class="menu">
                   <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resource.Faculty_One, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = 1 }, null)</li>
                   <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resource.Faculty_Three, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = 3 }, null)</li>
                   <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resource.Faculty_Five, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = 5 }, null)</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="divider"></div>                                                                                    
                <ul class="menu">
                   <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resource.Faculty_Two, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = 2 }, null)</li>
                   <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resource.Faculty_Four, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = 4 }, null)</li>
                   <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resource.Faculty_Six, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = 6 }, null)</li>
            </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to do the same but not quite sure what element to open close where/when e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 hidden-sm">
            <h4>@Resource.Title</h4>
            <p>@Resource.Header_Date</p>
            <img src="~/Content/Images/student.png" alt="student" />
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9">
            <h4>@Resource.Header_ListTitle</h4>
            <div class="row">
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    if (counter != 0 && counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        @:</li>
        @:<li>
    }
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="divider"></div>
        @* what to do here? *@
       </div>
       counter++;
}
</div><!-- /end row -->
```

It's totally confusing. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Just create a view model with 2 collection properties so you can use simple loops.

Comment: You mean like if i use ViewBag to split the list of faculties into 2 different lists and have e.g. ViewBag.ListOne and ViewBag.ListTwo?

Comment: I would not recommend `ViewBag (a view model would be better), but 2 `ViewBag` properties will still work

Comment: Like the following? List<Faculties> list1 = null;
            List<Faculties> list2 = null;
            var faculties = db.Faculties.ToList();
            foreach(var faculty in faculties)
            {
                if(faculty.ID % 2 == 0)
                {
                    list1.Add(faculty);
                }
                else
                {
                    list2.Add(faculty);
                }
            }
            ViewBag.ListOne = list1;
            ViewBag.ListTwo = list2;

            return View(faculties);

Comment: Something like that would work (except that it needs to be  `List<Faculties> list1 = new List<Faculties>;` etc otherwise you will throw an exception) - its much better to put that type of code in your controller rather that the view

Comment: Btw i am assigning the Model from within Index ActionResult and it works fine for the very first time. All the faculties are listed down. However if i click a link calling another action i get an exception object not set to reference blah blah. It is a partial view MENU that i render in the _layout. Any ideas about what approach to be used? Thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114323/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-elizabeth-dimova).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i ended with:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 hidden-sm">
            <h4>@Resource.Title</h4>
            <p>@Resource.Header_Date</p>
            <img src="~/Content/Images/student.png" alt="student" />
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9">
            <h4>@Resource.Header_ListTitle</h4>
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <ul class="menu">
                   @foreach (var item in Model.Where(e => e.ID % 2 == 0))
                   {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.FacultyName, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = item.ID }, null)</li>
                   }
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="divider"></div>                                                                                    
                <ul class="menu">
                   @foreach (var item in Model.Where(e => e.ID % 2 != 0))
                   {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.FacultyName, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = item.ID }, null)</li>
                   }
            </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Actually it was much simpler than i thought. Thank you guys for all inputs. It's much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator:

```
<div class="divider"></div>
        <ul class="menu">
                   <li>@Html.ActionLink(counter % 2 == 0 ?Resource.Faculty_Two : Resource.Faculty_One, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = counter % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1 }, null)</li>
                   <li>@Html.ActionLink(counter % 2 == 0 ?Resource.Faculty_Four : Resource.Faculty_Three, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = counter % 2 == 0 ? 4 : 3 }, null)</li>
                   <li>@Html.ActionLink(counter % 2 == 0 ?Resource.Faculty_Six : Resource.Faculty_Five, "Faculty", "Home", new { id = counter % 2 == 0 ? 6 : 5 }, null)</li>
            </ul>
       </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally you will need two loops one for odd and one for even id's. First loop may look like this:

```
 <ul>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resource.Faculty_Three, "Faculty", item.XXX, new { id = counter }, null)</li>
    }

    counter++;
}
</ul>
```

Generally you want to generate full HTML element inside Razor code block (`foreach`, `if` etc.), so avoid things like:

```
if (foo) {
  @: <li>
}

if (foo) {
  @: </li>
}
```

that will NOT WORK, besides Razor by default escapes `<` and `>` characters, you need to use `@Html.Raw` to put them in output. Better way is to structure your view so that every element is generated as whole:
`<li>foo</li>`. If you want to avoid code duplication you may want to look at Razor helpers: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor

Comment: Hmm OK but my bigger problem is where i open <UL> tags and where i close them etc. etc. Thx

Comment: You should open and close them inside the same `{ }` block, just like in my example inside `if`